# How to compose a 3d array from 3 1d arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

My code is as follows:

```
a = [.325 81 14; .272 105 26; .310 130 35];
b = [.305 75 18; .250 91 23; .285 126 41];
c = [.315 88 15; .265 95 21; .297 113 31];
abc(:,:,1) = a;
abc(:,:,2) = b;
abc(:,:,3) = c;
```

Essentially, what I want to do is make `abc` a 3d array of `a`, `b` and `c` with `a` on the first page, `b` on the second page, and `c` on the third page. However, when I input this into the command window, I get the following error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

What's wrong with what I'm doing? I read a lot of similar posts where what I wrote was suggested, but my code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Add a `clear abc` at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible the variable `abc` already exists in your workspace, which would give you the error you're seeing. A better way of creating your 3D matrix is to use the `cat` command:

```
abc = cat(3,a,b,c);
```

`cat` concatenates the specified variables along the specified dimension (in this case the 3rd dimension).